# How to determine whether a sales campaign is effective?

Tags: application

Assuming that I have an online ecommerce store. Recently, for one of the products, I want to run a sales campaign for the product for a period of time. The effectiveness is defined solely in terms of increasing sales.

But the problem is I have no idea how to measure this. From my experience, sales volume fluctuates from month to month, and there could be other factors ( undetected) that dampen or excites my sales record. There are just too many variables, unknown and known involved and very difficult to disentangle them.

Doing controlled experiment like A/B testing the webpages( showing two versions of webpages to different visitors, one with promotion, one without promotion) is simply not practical, because the visitors may not buy instantly. They might buy after a while, so they are in a rude surprise to find that the price has changed so suddenly.

Even if it is practical, I don't have the resources to invest in A/B testing, my funds are very limited.

How to determine, and what are the statistical valid experiments that I can do, to check whether my sales campaign is effective or not?

Comment: Have a look at [cumulative gains and lift charts](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/lift_chart/lift_chart.html).

Comment: @MarcClaesen, I am sorry, but I don't quite understand what you suggest has anything to do with my question... mind to elaborate?